# Is there a Stack Exchange API allows research on the body?

Tags: support, search

I want to use the Stack Exchange API to perform research on the question/answer's body but it seems impossible.

Is that the case?  If not, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: The [`/search/advanced` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search), added in API version 2.1, allows you to search on *question* bodies (not answers, alas) using the `q` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to search in the body with the api stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

In order to access the body of a post, you need to create a filter that includes this information. You create a filter using the [`/filters/create`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter) method:

> http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/filters/create?include=question.body;answer.body

The response from that URL will look something like this:

```
{
  "items": [{
    "filter":"!9Tk5izFWA",
  ...
}
```

As you can see, the new filter is identified by the string `!9Tk5izFWA`. You need to then pass this as the `filter` parameter to any request that you want to obtain the post body on.

Example:

> http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions?site=stackoverflow&filter=!9Tk5izFWA

---

**Edit:** upon further clarification, the method you are looking for is [`/search`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search). The example would now become:

> http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/search?site=stackoverflow&filter=!9Tk5izFWA&intitle=java

This example will search for all questions that contain the string "java" in the title.

Comment: Thank's but sorry again, I want to search in the body not only in the title. I think the api not provide this service.

Comment: @taoder: That is correct - the API does not provide a means of searching within the post body. You could, however, use the data dumps.

Comment: Yes, I know. I do a comparison between this two method use of the api and the search engine of stackoverflow and in an other hand the use of the data dump.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2.2 version of the API a new end-point [/search/advanced](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) got added.

> Search the site for questions using most of the on-site search options.

That API does take a body parameter, allowing you to find only questions with a certain term in the body.

Here is how you use it to find questions with the word *search* in it:

> [`2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&body=search`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&body=search&site=stackapps)

The items array returns instances of the [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) type.

Unfortunately it will not return answers.